# disabling cookies in IE8

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-8

I'm testing my Asp.Net application from localhost to check how it behaves when cookies are disabled. I tried blocking the cookies in IE8, by setting it at

Tools -> Internet Options -> Privacy -> Advanced

and selecting "Block" for both "First-party Cookies" and "Third-party Cookies". However, when I run my application, the cookies still get created.

Can you let me know how I can disable cookies in IE8.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the Dev Tools. Hit F12, go to Cache > Disable Cookies.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that these setting are meant for Internet Zone. For your localhost site, I suggest that you use hosts entry to map some arbitrary domain name (say www.xyz.com) to localhost, add this site as blocked site (use sites button on privacy tab) and access your app using this address.